# How to add TMail to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I thought TMail was included in Rails. But when I try to call it, I got error:

```
email = TMail::Mail.parse("From mikel@example.org\nReceived by.... etc")
NameError: uninitialized constant TMail
```

When I `require 'tmail'` on my console, I also got error:

```
require 'tmail'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- tmail
```

I already installed tmail using `sudo gem install tmail`

My question is: how can I add TMail to Rails app? I am using Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the gem inside your Gemfile

```
gem 'tmail'
```

then run `bundle install`

Comment: Thanks. I got `tmail` in my Rails gem now, but I have issue with parsing: `email = TMail::Mail.parse("From mikel@example.org\nReceived by.... etc")` gives: `TMail::SyntaxError: wrong mail header: '"Received by.... etc"'`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Nevermind, tmail is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.1+. I'll change to `mail` gem.

Comment: That's a good sign (TMail is loading). I don't know TMail but you can post another question for your issue, I'm sure you'll get an answer :)